# Linqpad Casting error entity object to IObjectContextAdapter

Tags: linqpad

I'm using Linqpad v4.37.3 trying to connect to an build using entity framework 4.1. I've been able to go through the wizard and create the connection. I'm using a connection string of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Common.Database.DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/Common.Database.DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/Common.Database.DatabaseModel.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=ServerAddress;
         Initial Catalog=database;User ID=username;Password=password;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName='System.Data.EntityClient' />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I test the connection it say sucessful. But when I try to expand the database I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'EFEntities' to type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectcontextAdapter'.

I'm not quite sure what I need to change to get this work and I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem.

Comment: There's a new beta 4.37.4? Does this fix it? Does this work in an older version?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with assembly compatibility and support for EF 4.1 vs 4.2: Fusion is a nasty beast at times. Try the latest (4.37.5) beta - it contains a re-write of the interface to EntityFramework. The new version of LINQPad no longer references EntityFramework.dll statically - instead it uses Reflection to call EF members and Reflection.Emit to implement interfaces based on the actual EF assembly that you're referencing. This should get rid of the problem you're experiencing. Let me know if there are any glitches in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.37.5 beta solved the 'IObjectcontextAdapter' problem for me.

I'm now able to see the entites in the object-browser on the left.

However, every query/statement I'm trying execute just results in the following error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
```

It seems to happen before it's even hitting the EF part of things.

If I try to run the following as a C# program:

```
void Main()
{
    HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.Initialize();
}
```

or just

```
void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i++; i < 100)
    {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

- I get the same error, so it seems not to be directly EF related. However if I connect directly to a SQL database, I have no problems executing statements.

I'm using EF 4.1.

Edit: Sorry, this should have been a reply to Joe Albahari's answer.

Comment: Is there any more info about the error in %localappdata%\linqpad\logs\log.txt?

Comment: @JoeAlbahari I don't have that file or folder. All I have is AutoCompletionCache40 and UserOptions.xml. Should this log-file be "turned on" somewhere to log to it?